# php - Is strpos the fastest way to search for a string in a large body of text?

Tags: php, string, hash, string-search

```
if (strpos(htmlentities($storage->getMessage($i)),'chocolate'))
```

Hi, I'm using gmail oauth access to find specific text strings in email addresses.  Is there a way to find text instances quicker and more efficiently than using strpos in the above code?  Should I be using a hash technique?

Comment: You **must** use the strict comparison operator with the `strpos()` function. This is because it may return an integer `0`, which means the string 'chocolate' was found at the start of the string. With the statement as you have it, this would evaluate to `FALSE`. Correct would be `if (strpos(htmlentities($storage->getMessage($i)), 'chocolate') !== FALSE)`

Comment: Why are you using `htmlentities()`? It slows everything down.

Comment: Because I'm also searching if it's in the html - would it take link urls into consideration if I dropped the htmlentities tag?

Comment: for example:  <a href="http://chocoloatefactory.com">Bob's Site</a> - would this still return true if I omitted htmlentities?

Comment: htmlentities doesn't change anything but specific characters like the quotation mark. It would be best to make sure they're also not encoded in the string you're searching, and not use that function in this case. For your example string "chocolate" the entities make no difference.

Comment: @Bob It wouldn't make a difference. In your example, `strpos` finds both `chocoloate` (sic) and `Site` with or without `htmlentities()`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the PHP manual, yes- `strpos()` is the quickest way to determine if one string contains another.

> **Note:**
>
> If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack,
>      use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.

This is quoted time and again in any php.net article about other string comparators (I pulled this one from `strstr()`)

Although there are two changes that should be made to your statement.

```
if (strpos($storage->getMessage($i),'chocolate') !== FALSE)
```

This is because `if(0)` evaluates to false (and therefore doesn't run), however `strpos()` can return 0 if the needle is at the very beginning (position 0) of the haystack. Also, removing `htmlentities()` will make your code run a lot faster. All that `htmlentities()` does is replace certain characters with their appropriate HTML equivalent. For instance, it replaces every `&` with `&amp;`

As you can imagine, checking **every** character in a string individually and replacing many of them takes extra memory and processor power. Not only that, but it's unnecessary if you plan on just doing a text comparison. For instance, compare the following statements:

```
strpos('Billy & Sally', '&'); // 6
strpos('Billy &amp; Sally', '&'); // 6
strpos('Billy & Sally', 'S'); // 8
strpos('Billy &amp; Sally', 'S') // 12
```

Or, in the worst case, you may even cause something true to evaluate to false.

```
strpos('<img src...', '<'); // 0
strpos('&lt;img src...','<'); // FALSE
```

In order to circumvent this you'd end up using even more HTML entities.

```
strpos('&lt;img src...', '&lt;'); // 0
```

But this, as you can imagine, is not only annoying to code but gets redundant. You're better off excluding HTML entities entirely. Usually HTML entities is only used when you're outputting text. Not comparing.

Answer (score 2):

**strpos** is likely to be faster than **preg_match** and the alternatives in this case, the best idea would be to do some benchmarks of your own with real example data and see what is best for your needs, although that may be overdoing it. Don't worry too much about performance until it starts to become a problem

Comment: it's already somewhat of a problem.  I'm trying to quickly search for this string is user's email inboxes, and it takes about 2 seconds to sort through a single email.  I would like to get this number down to at least a half a second.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is in the strpos, or with the inbox search? If you are using imap let me know I may be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

2024 Update,

If running php 8 it appears [str_contains](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) is a faster method.

Comment: Upon what do you base this claim?

Answer (score -1):

[strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) return the begin position of first occurrence of string, if no match will return Null so statement is fairly usable.

```
if (!is_null(strpos($storage->getMessage($i),'chocolate'))) {}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider reformatting your post so that it's easier to understand what is code and what is not.

Comment: `strpos` **never returns null**, it returns `false`